# Proving that two circles in the Complex Plane intersect orthogonally?

Tags: complex-numbers, contest-math, circles

I've been stuck on this question for the better part of a day now:

> Let $a$ be a non-zero complex number such that $|a| \neq 1$. Let $P$ be the point $a$ in the complex plane, and let $Q$ be the point $\frac{1}{\bar a}$, Let $C_1$ be the circle $\{z:|z| = 1\}$ and let $C_2$ be any circle that passes through both $P$ and $Q$. Show that $C_1$ and $C_2$ intersect orthogonally.

I don't even know how to begin solving this question, but here are a few things which I've tried to do:

- Figure out that $\{z:|z| = 1\}$ refers to the unit circle.
- Tried to find an expression for the centre $z$ of $C_2$ using $|z-a| = |z-\frac{1}{\bar a}|$ to no avail — I opened up the expression as $(z-a)(\bar z-\bar a) = (z-\frac{1}{\bar a})(\bar z-\frac{1}{a})$. I also tried using the fact that $|z-a| + |z- \frac{1}{\bar a}| = |a-\frac{1}{\bar a}|.$
- Reasoned that if $z_1$ is the point of interception then $\tan (\frac{-1}{\arg{z_1}})$ would be the slope of the tangent of $C_2$.

Are any of these approaches right? I would appreciate a hint.

---

Edit: **I should mention that I have only an advanced high-school understanding of complex numbers. This question is from a book that meant to be solved by high-schoolers.**

Comment: When working with circles it's often easier to use the polar form of complex numbers rather than the Cartesian form. In particular the arguments of $a$ and $1/a$ have a simple relationship that may be of use here.

Comment: What do you mean by saying “intersect orthogonally”?

Comment: @fantasie It means that their tangents at the point of intersection are at $90°$ angles.

Comment: @CyclotomicField AFAIK $\frac{1}{\bar a} = \frac{a}{|a|^2}$, so shouldn't the arguments be equal?

Comment: @Lt.Commander.Data I kind of doubt that, for the line through $2e^{\pi/4}$ and its inverse (the circle passing through whose radius $\to\infty$)  doesn’t intersect $C_1$ with orthogonal tangents.

Comment: If I have two complex numbers in the form $re^\theta$ with $r$ the radius and $\theta$ the argument then what happens when you multiply them together? What can you say about the radius and argument? I recommend sketching a few examples of $z_1z_2=z_3$ by hand to see what's going on here.

Comment: My way of going about this is via Möbius transformations. Map the unit circle to $\mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}$, and note that $a$ and $1/\bar{a}$ are mapped to conjugate points.

Comment: Perform inversion wrt the unit circle. You'll find that the other circle inverts to itself. This is enough to conclude the desired.

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm sorry but I have a very elementary understanding of complex numbers, ie. I've just learnt the polar and exponential forms of writing them down. Is there a more elementary way to solve this? This question is meant for advanced high-schoolers.

Comment: @EdwardH Is there an easier way to approach this problem wrt my edit?

Comment: Then I guess Euclidean geometry is the way to go. There are probably more elegant ways, but noting that a circle with centre $c$ and radius $r$ intersects the unit circle orthogonally if and only if $\lvert c\rvert^2 = r^2 + 1$ (Pythagoras) and that the centre of a circle passing trough two points $u$ and $v$ lies on the line $\frac{1}{2}(u+v) + it(u-v),\: t\in \mathbb{R}$ should lead to a manageable task. It may help to assume $a$ is real and positive (rotations don't change angles).

Comment: @fantasie your doubt is respectable but the assertion is true...

Comment: Once you have noticed that $a=re^{i\alpha}$ and $b:=1/\bar{a}=\frac1re^{i\alpha}$ are aligned with the origin, you will see that you are in a classical configuration called [**Apollonian circles**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_circles) where any of the blue circles are orthogonal to any of the red circles (colors of the first figure of this article).